# Торговали мы не()даром//Неуказанным товаром;

Tags: семантика, синтаксис

Торговали мы недаром
Неуказанным товаром;

Почему здесь слитное написание?
Как вообще надо понимать фразу?

Подсказка: см метку.

Answer (score 3):

Здесь НЕДАРОМ  наречие со значением "не зря". (Если бы писалось раздельно, то имелось бы в виду "торговали не даром, а дорого").

О НЕУКАЗАННОМ товаре хорошо написано здесь: http://touch.otvet.mail.ru/question/53672540

В двух словах - это товар, принадлежащий купцам

Comment: Тэк-с... Ну допусти "не зря". Хотя это было бы слишком просто...)))
А как Вы понимаете всю фразу?  
Недаром неуказанным - или недаром торговали?  
  
Насчет "неуказанного". Спасибо за ссылку. Но у меня на этот счет есть своё мнение. Я его пока попридержу. А в викторинах столько всего понаворочено...

Comment: Думаю,  что недаром торговали. Вариант "недаром неуказанным" даже не рассматривала, наверно, мешает новая строка и пауза (хотя пауза вещь спорная, зависит от прочтения).

Comment: А если "недаром торговали", то почему "недаром" слитно? 
И как вообще можно "торговать даром"?

Comment: Недаром торговали = не зря торговали, благополучно прошел торг и пр. 

Даром можно только отдать, это уже не продажа.

Comment: Так "не зря", "не случайно" или с "выгодой"? В данном контексте это принципиальная разница. "Не зря" можно и себе в убыток торговать - из каких-то высших соображений, ожидая обвала цен, например. А если с выгодой - то это уже вариант прямого значения - "не даром".  
  
Впрочем, ладно. Вы вполне последовательно и однозначно связываете "недаром" с "торговали" и только с ним. При таком подходе трактовка "неуказанный" как "личный", принадлежащий купцам выглядит в обще-то логичной.

Comment: Я признаюсь, я все никак не могу решить, писать ли тут свои "исследования" - все-таки местный формат обсуждения как-то не очень способствует...  Даи троллинг свирепствует. (((   
А писать такие вещи ради того чтобы "застолбить" как-то не приучен. Мне нужен нормальный научный (ну или квазинаучный) спор...  
  
Сейчас правда на то и времени нет, но к осени, видимо, появится. Вот, пока пока набираю "статистику" ))).

Answer (score 2):

Если бы НЕДАРОМ относилось к "НЕ указанным" как зависимое от него слово, тогда причастие надо было бы писать с НЕ раздельно. 
У нас - слитное написание НЕУКАЗАННЫМ. Значит, НЕДАРОМ относится не к причастию, а к глаголу ТОРГОВАЛИ.

Comment: А вот тут надо крепко спорить. Во-первых само правило о зависимом слове весьма неоднозначно, во-вторых наречия обычно не входят в список "зависимых" слов.

Comment: Наречие бывает зависимым от причастия: кошенный ВЧЕРА луг, не выученное ВОВРЕМЯ правило. Причастие, к которому относится наречие МЕРЫ и СТЕПЕНИ (в высшей степени и очень, слишком и почти,
совершенно, абсолютно, полностью, довольно,отчасти и гораздо,
крайне, вполне,  весьма) пишется с НЕ слитно, остальные зависимые от причастия наречия требуют  раздельного написания НЕ.

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, по смыслу фразы можно с равным правом написать и слитно, и раздельно, потому что имеется в виду, что гости(торговые агенты царя)сообщают об успешной собственной торговле(не даром, а за большие деньги, с большой прибылью, недаром = не без причины, не без цели (по Ожегову), не зря, т.е. с целью наживы) .Кстати, где-то в старых изданиях видела и раздельное написание,  обращала на это внимание, но решила,что это описка. Понятно, что торговля "указанным", т.е. перечисленным в указе("декларации"),товаром несёт прибыль царю, а не им, потому они и говорят, что на этот раз торговали в свой карман,не указывая точных цифр по понятным причинам.

Comment: Людмила, тот же вопрос.  Недаром неуказанным или не даром торговали. 
И еще. Почему Вы тоже трактуете "указанный" как относящийся к указу? Ни одного убедительного обоснования не вижу.

Comment: Указанный - т.е. его указали в перечне, в указе ,которым предписывалось выделить кредит, выдать товар по перечню, назначить переводчиков из приказов и т.п.В пушкинских сказках чудесное совмещалось с реальным:товар для госторговли поступал из госуд. складов, для найма кораблей получалась субсидия, в случае кораблекрушения убытки могли быть возмещены, но и  вместо огромной прибыли "гости" довольствовались установленным вознаграждением. Огромную прибыль они получали только от "неуказанных", неучтённых в указе товаров. О ней и речь.Потому "недаром неуказанным"торговали - прибыльно, потому и рады.

Comment: Получается, что торговля указанным товаром - торговля даром, неуказанным-недаром (с большой прибылью)

Comment: Ну что там с чем совмещалось - это еще большой вопрос. Можно такого понапридумывать исходя лишь из собственной прихости... Я с таким сталкивался.  
Но об указе потом, коли ссылок все равно нет. А сначала, всё-таки хотелось бы услышать, "недаром неуказанным" или "недаром торговали". Если "недаром торговали", то не логичнее ли будет писать раздельно? тут то в прямом значении получается. Нет?

Comment: получается "недаром неуказанным"

Comment: Насчёт относимости к указу - "указанный" не от слова "указ", а от "указать" - есть такое значение:"только полн. Установленный, намеченный кем-чем-нибудь".(http://www.onlinedics.ru/slovar/ushakov/u/ukazannyj.htmlу ).Но указаны эти товары в данном случае в указе, который пишут для "гостей".

Answer (score 0):

Тут повтор вопроса возник.

Я даю свое видение. 
"Недаром" должно по смыслу относиться к причастию. Довольно странным по смыслу было бы сочетание "торговали недаром". А кто у нас даром-то торгует?
Рассуждения о том, что наречие является-де зависимым словом меня, честно говоря, совсем не убедили - ни тогда, ни сейчас. Ну не должно быть такого, чтобы подобное наречие сказывалось на орфографии причастия. Ни вообще - ни в данном случае.

А вот что касается смысла "неуказанный"... Мне видится, что сведение его к "указу" превращает его в обычное прилагательное. Не отглагольное даже. Но на это есть прилагательное "указной". А по грамматической роли в предположении "указа" получается, что тут стопроцентное причастие. Ведь в этом случае речь идет о **состоянии** товара.
Иное дело при трактовке "указанного" как происходящего от глагола указывать, с указом напрямую не связанным. Тогда перед нами типичное отглагольное прилагательное (свойство товара, качество). В сочетании с "недаром" смысл выглядит вполне определенным  - речь идет о контрабанде.
Единственное сомнение: а не примеряю ли я к сказочному миру Пушкина реалии мира настоящего, более того - современно нам, а не Пушкину?
Впрочем, с "указом" таких сомнений будет даже поболее.

Ну а из всего этого вытекает и слитное написание.